# @Max and @Min is not working for method parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a rest Endpoint defined in the Java controller which has @Validated annotation, the method has @Min and @max annotation for the request param but when i invoke the API from postman even for the requestId with 1-9 characters it returns 400 error with the message mentioned inside annotation, but after updating to use @size annotation its working as expected. Why does @Max or @min fail for the request parameter but @Size works

Updating to below annotation worked

@Size(min = 1, max = 10, message = "Request Id size must be between 1 and 10")

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/request")
public class StatusController { 

@GetMapping(path = "/status/{requestId}")
public Entity getStatus(@Min(value = 1, message = "Id size must be between 1 and 10")
                        @Max(value = 10, message = "Id size must be between 1 and 10")
                        @NotNull(message = "Id cannot be null")
                        @PathVariable String requestId)  { ..... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javax.validation.constraints @Min and @Max apply to numeric types.

Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html

and https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html

Since your path variable is a String, you will need to use @Size like you have discovered.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Since our request ID is an hexadecimal value and not an int, replacing the dataType to int will throw an error hence we will continue to use the @Size.